# Writing Apache2 Logs to stdout/stderr?

Tags: apache-2.2, docker

I'm running Apache2 in a docker container, and want to write nothing to the disk, writing logs to stdout and stderr. I've seen a few different ways to do this ([Supervisord and stdout/stderr](https://serverfault.com/questions/523555/supervisord-and-stdout-stderr),  [Apache access log to stdout](https://serverfault.com/questions/71667/apache-access-log-to-stdout)) but these seem like hacks. Is there no way to do this by default?

To be clear, I do not want to tail the log, since that will result in things being written to the disk in the container.

Comment: Aren't you going to want those logs to be easily accessible for troubleshooting/debugging purposes? Why not just write them to a (r)syslog server instead?

Comment: @HTTP500 - They get captured on the outside of the docker container.

Comment: If you use: FROM php:5.6-apache, that already includes logs to stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
  ErrorLog /dev/stderr
  TransferLog /dev/stdout
```

works on ubuntu and centos fo me

Comment: which file should it go into etc pls

Comment: This goes in you `domain.conf` file or `.htaccess` if you aren't using a `conf`.

Comment: For _Alpine Linux_ you set it in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as `ErrorLog /dev/stderr` and `CustomLog /dev/stdout combined`

Answer (score 39):

How about placing this in your Dockerfile after the apache2 package is installed?

```
RUN ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Assuming that this is the path of the logs.  It is for Ubuntu 14.04 and also works for Ubuntu 16.04.

**Note: if you're certain that the symbolic links `/dev/stdout` or `/proc/stderr` are there, then you may also use those.  I prefer the path to the real file as this is guaranteed present.**

Comment: works great also with Ubuntu 16.04 :)

Comment: Damn, that's an ingenious hack! Apache tries to open a regular file, but gets redirected via symlink to its own stdout from its own perspective.

Comment: Just want to say thanks... the official apache httpd 2.4 docker container fails to write logs after enabling ssl. Adding these lines + ssl_request_log to the Dockerfile that pulls from httpd2.4 worked.

Comment: You can abbreviate /proc/self/fd/1 as /dev/stdout.  They're exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ChuckAdams - they are a soft link and normally there, but no guarantees when building images that they are present.  Especially cut down micro images.  Whereas the kernel will always export /proc/self/fd/1 & 2.

Comment: is `/proc/self` a real thing?

Comment: I have one more log file in the `/var/log/apache2` folder last time I checked

Comment: Any explanation for why this works? (It does seem to).

Comment: @AlexanderMills - See the proc fs documentation.  Search for "self".  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.  It always refers to the process the current process.  e.g. ls /proc/self represents "ls".  Apache /proc/self refers to the Apache process.  That's why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically an answer asked for but maybe a better way, depending on your scenario, would be to to not log to stdout/stderr at all. Just pipe the logs to cat in a JSON format. This would remove the need to differentiate the streams as the json could have the data needed in it to distinguish them. eg something along the lines of the following. This can then be ingested much more easily into something like graylog

```
GlobalLog "| cat - " gelf
ErrorLog "| cat - " 

LogFormat "{ \"apache_log\": \"ACCESS\", \"app_name\": \"apache\",  \"Connection\": \"%{X-Forwarded-Proto}i:%{X-Forwarded-Port}i \", \"X-Forwarded-For\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\",  \"version\": \"1.1\", \"vhost\": \"%V\", \"short_message\": \"%r\", \"timestamp\": %{%s}t, \"level\": 6, \"user_agent\": \"%{User-Agent}i\", \"source_ip\": \"%a\", \"duration_usec\": %D, \"duration_sec\": %T, \"request_size_byte\": %O, \"http_status\": %s, \"http_request_path\": \"%U\", \"http_request\": \"%U%q\", \"http_method\": \"%m\", \"http_referer\": \"%{Referer}i\", \"X-Powered-By\": \"%{X-Powered-By}i\" }" gelf

ErrorLogFormat "{ \"app_name\": \"apache\",  \"apache_log\": \"ERROR\", \"time\":\"%{%Y-%m-%d}tT%{%T}t.%{msec_frac}tZ\", \"function\" : \"[%-m:%l]\" , \"process\" : \" [pid %P:tid %T] \" , \"message\" : \"%M\" ,\ \"referer\"\ : \" %{Referer}i \" }"
```

There is also a gelf logging module, so you can stream direct from apache to a graylog type server as well if you wish